# Modifying aspect ratio of a plot in R

Tags: r, graphics, plot

Here is my first plot

```
par(bg="white")
image(m, main = paste("generation: ",generation), ylab="", col=heat.colors(100), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="")
```

[image]

It is a square, and I'd like it to be a rectangle. So I did

```
par(bg="white", mar=c(16,1,16,1))
        image(m, main = paste("generation: ",generation), ylab="", col=heat.colors(100), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="")
```

[image]

But then the title (`main`) is really far away from the plot. So I did

```
par(bg="white", mar=c(16,1,16,1))
        image(m, ylab="", col=heat.colors(100), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="")
        legend(0.32, 3.5, paste("Generation: ", IntFormat(generation, 4)), border="white", xpd=TRUE, box.col="white", cex=1.5)
```

[image]

Well.. I wouldn't say it is splendid, but I was satisfied. So let's put that into a .png

```
png(paste0(folder.images, "pg_",IntFormat(generation,4),".png"))
        par(bg="white", mar=c(16,1,16,1))
        image(m, ylab="", col=heat.colors(100), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="")
        legend(0.32, 3.5, paste("Generation: ", IntFormat(generation, 4)), border="white", xpd=TRUE, box.col="white", cex=1.5)
        dev.off()
```

and here is what the .png looks like!

[image]

---

1. Is there a better solution to make a rectangle out of my square than using the parameter `mar` that force me to add a title with `legend` and to search by trial and error where the center to the picture is for the title.
2. Why is the .png different from what is shown in the R window?

Comment: 1) see "asp" in `?par`; 2) two different devices

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I indeed stumble upon this thing and tried but with no success. `asp` is not a graphical parameter, so I don't thing I can use it in `par(..)` and it doesn't seem to have any impact when used in `image(..)` (doesn't raise any error though).

Comment: my mistake, asp is under plot.window, but either way you can pass it via `image`.. oh you *want*  a rectangle. can you post a working example

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand how `asp` works. Why is the following not reshaped horizontally: `image(matrix(1:10, ncol=1), asp=0.1)` ?

Comment: You have `width` and `height` arguments in `png`.

Comment: Oh yes, I tried that as well but for whatever values I chose I always got `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`. `width` and `height` worked with `pdf()` though.... but I'd like to have `.png`!

Comment: If it works with pdf, make a pdf then convert it into png, maybe.

Comment: I had issue with ImageMagick in doing so, I lost quality. Might be another issue to solve, but I guess the R problem I am having should solvable as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could achieve this:

```
png("test.png", res = 150, width = 8, height = 1, units = "in")
par(mar = c(1,1,1,1))
image(matrix(1:10, ncol=1), ylab="", col=heat.colors(100), xaxt="n", 
      yaxt="n", xlab="", main="Generation: 0001")
dev.off()
```

[image]